# why counter value increment and decrement only first time?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q8nsfz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Store} from '@ngrx/store';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

import * as fromApp from './app.store';
import {DecrementCounter, IncrementCounter} from './store/counter.action';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  c: Observable<object>;

  constructor(private store: Store<fromApp.AppState>) {
  }

  incrementCounter() {
     this.store.dispatch(new IncrementCounter());
  }

  decrementCounter() {
    this.store.dispatch(new DecrementCounter());
  }
  ngOnInit(){
    this.c =this.store.select('counterValue');

  }
}
```

Hi

can you please tell me why my counter value increment and decrement only first time .I have two button `increment` and `decrement` the counter value change on button click .but my value change only first time .it show `0` initial value which is correct but after that it don't work why ?

Comment: Could you share the store code?

Comment: I think you are doing a silly mistake in counter.reducer.ts..check my answer with @Swoox

Comment: ok i will check n update u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Replace initialState.counter + 1 to state.counter + 1;

  switch (action.type) {
    case CounterActions.INCREMENT:
      const counter = state.counter + 1;
      return {...state, counter};
    case CounterActions.DECREMENT:
      const currentCounter = state.counter - 1;
      return {...state, counter: currentCounter};
    default :
      return state;
  }
```

Comment: see it works https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q8nsfz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: without @swooz anser

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple every time when you call the function: `incrementCounter` you make a new class `new IncrementCounter()`. So every time when you call this function it will excute the same thing.

What you need to do is make this new class on the scope of the component:

```
private incrementClass = new IncrementCounter();
private decrementClass = new DecrementCounter();

  constructor(private store: Store<fromApp.AppState>) {
  }

  incrementCounter() {
     this.store.dispatch(this.incrementClass);
  }

  decrementCounter() {
    this.store.dispatch(this.decrementClass);
  }
```

Comment: can you share your link

Comment: it works without your code why ? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q8nsfz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: pls remove your anser

Answer (score 0):

change your "counterReducer function"

```
export function counterReducer(state = initialState, action: CounterActions.CounterManagment) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CounterActions.INCREMENT:
      const counter = initialState.counter++; //see, you increment the variable initialState.counter, and then return it
      return {...state, counter};
    case CounterActions.DECREMENT:
      const currentCounter = initialState.counter--;
      return {...state, counter: currentCounter}; //idem decrement
    default :
      return state;
  }
}
```